# count Pixel coordinates x and y

Tags: c++, image, opencv

i try this code to summation the pixels coordinates (x,y) in the image

this is the code

```
#include<cv.h>
#include<cvaux.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<highgui.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<cxtypes.h> // for cvarr 
using namespace std;
// This program to count the pixel value in the gray image
void main()
{
    IplImage* image;
    int w,h;
    char* filename;
    filename="D:\\Recognition\\Image Crop\\7.jpg";
    image=cvLoadImage(filename,0); //for grayscal image
    // Get image attribute
    w=image->width; //image width
    h=image->height; //image height
    cout<<"1. image width "<<w<<"\n2. image height "<<h<<"  \n";
    int Sx,Sy;
    const CvArr* arr;
    CvScalar se; // to store the num
    for(int x=0;x>image->width;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;image->height;y++)
        {
            se=cvGet2D(image,x,y);
            Sx=se.val[y];
            Sx+=Sx;
        }
        Sy=se.val[x];
        Sy+=Sy;
    }
    cout<<"3. sum x ="<<Sx<<"\n4. sum y ="<<Sy<<" \n";
}
```

i am trying to calculate the sum of pixel coordinates x and y .

Comment: What's the expected output, and what's the actual output?

Comment: This must be C++. In C, a string cannot be the rightmost operand of a << shift operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's with these loops?

```
for(int x=0;x>image->width;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;image->height;y++)
```

Should be:

```
for(int x=0;x<image->width;x++)
{
    for(int y=0;y<image->height;y++)
```

right?

Plus also, what's with this?:

```
        Sx=se.val[y];
        Sx+=Sx;
```

You're resetting `Sx` every loop iteration and then doubling it, but then throwing that computation away next loop iteration.  Similar issues with the `Sy`.

I encourage you take a look at your program line by line and really think about what it's doing before you post questions publically.

Comment: Thanks for replay , but i modify the code 
the output is out of range