# error in this code out of range

Tags: c++, image, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [count Pixel coordinates x and y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767057/count-pixel-coordinates-x-and-y)

i am try this code to make summation of pixel coordinates value

this is the code

```
#include<cv.h>
#include<cvaux.h>
#include<highgui.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<cxtypes.h> // for cvarr 
using namespace std;


void main()
{
    IplImage* image;
    int w,h;
    char* filename;
    filename="D:\\Recognition\\Image Crop\\7.jpg";
    image=cvLoadImage(filename,0); //load image from file 
    // Get image attribute
    w=image->width; //image width
    h=image->height; //image height
    cout<<"1. image width "<<w<<"\n2. image height "<<h<<"  \n";
    int Sx,Sy;
    const CvArr* arr; // msh 3arf aih lzmtha
    CvScalar se; // to store the num

    //loop 3shan 23di 3ala kol pixel
    for(int x=0;x<image->width;x++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<image->height;y++)
        {
            se=cvGet2D(image,x,y);
            Sx=se.val[y];
            Sx+=Sx;
        }
        Sy=se.val[x];
        Sy+=Sy;
    }
    cout<<"1. image width "<<w<<"\n2. image height "<<h<<"  \n";
    cout<<"3. sum x ="<<Sx<<"\n4. sum y ="<<Sy<<" \n";
}
```

this code for count or get the sum of the pixel P(x,y) sum of x and y in image

and this the output is value of width and height , but don't calculate value of x and y and make out of range in the output screen

any Help

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sx=se.val[y];
Sx+=Sx;
```

This is not doing what you think it is doing.

`a += b;` is the same as `a = a+b;`: On each iteration, you're overwriting the value of `Sx`, then adding it to itself (doubling it) and storing that value back in the `Sx` variable.  (Where it is overwritten on the next iteration.)